# How to select a row for every location for every day using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a database where some forecasts for two locations are stored. For every location there are forecasts for 3 days and for every day there are multiple forecasts every hour. **I want to select the average temp of 3 latest forecasts for each location for every day**. The location is saved as "location", each day is saved as "applicable_date" and for every day there is a forecast each hour saved as "created". I am trying something like this but does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `forecast` GROUP BY location
) GROUP BY applicable_date 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Please provide your tables structure, test data and desired result [mre]

Comment: Group by location and forecast datetime truncated till date. Get maximal forecast datetime per group.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav your query will give one max datetime per location, not "for every day".

Comment: You should just accept the best answer and then ask a new question.  Changing the question to add more requests is not a good idea, considering the answers/work already provided based on the original question.  You also neglected to provide detail about the version of MySQL you are using: `SELECT version();`  That would likely simplify the solution, for instance, if you're using MySQL 8.0 or better or MariaDB 10.2.2 or better.  It's tough to know if you wanted `AVG` over 3 days or the last 3 samples from each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be fine.  These return the entire forecast row for each day/location.

For version 8.0+:

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location, applicable_date ORDER BY created DESC ) AS rn
         FROM forecast
     )
SELECT *
  FROM cte
 WHERE rn = 1
;
```

For version 8.0+ and before:

```
SELECT f.*
  FROM (
       SELECT location, applicable_date
            , MAX(created) AS max_created
         FROM forecast
        GROUP BY location, applicable_date
     ) AS cte
  JOIN forecast AS f
    ON f.location        = cte.location
   AND f.applicable_date = cte.applicable_date
   AND f.created         = cte.max_created
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I want also to select "the_temp" of the last 3 forecasts for each location for every day

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT location, 
       CAST(created AS DATE) `date`, 
-- or  applicable_date `date`,
       MAX(created) last_datetime
FROM forecast
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: thank you this work! but I would like to return all row not only location and date

Comment: @user15924442 See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361508/10138734) provided by [@JonArmstrong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445629/jon-armstrong).